# MySQL queries performance comparison

Tags: mysql, performance

Between these 2 queries, is one faster than the other in MySQL 5.7.19?

```
select {some columns}
from
  table1 t1
  join table2 t2 using ({some columns})
where t1.col1=1
```

vs

```
select {some columns}
from
  (select {some columns} from table1 where col1=1) t1
  join table2 t2 using ({some columns})
```

assuming that all indexes are correctly set

Comment: _is one faster then the other?..._ What is stopping you from benchmarking on your own?

Comment: Dunno - why don't you try? The optimizer will probably create identical query plans. If you post a SQLFiddle, we can be more constructive.

Comment: @all I currently don't have the data yet, it will be 250M rows so I need theorical knowledge from people who know the answer

Comment: Please update http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0005cd/5 to show more of the problem domain - the query plans are not identical, so that is a pointer...

Comment: _I currently don't have the data yet..._ Create dummy data easily... theoretical answers will not help you in real life... even if they come from db experts

Comment: *even if they come from db experts*... actually that will help me

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0005cd/7) so we can experiment.

Your first query translates to:

```
select *  
from
  table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
  where t1.col1=1
```

And the execution plan is:

> id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
>
> 1 SIMPLE t1 ref id,col1 col1 4 const 2
>   100.00 Using index
>
> 1 SIMPLE t2 ref table1_id table1_id 4 db_9_0005cd.t1.id 1
>   100.00 Using index

This is pretty much as fast as it can possibly be.

Your second query becomes

```
 select *
from
  (select * from table1 where col1=1) as t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
```

And the execution plan is:

> id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
>
> 1 PRIMARY t2 index table1_id table1_id 4 3 100.00 Using index
>
> 1 PRIMARY ref 4 db_9_0005cd.t2.table1_id 2100.00
>
> 2 DERIVED table1 ref col1 col1 4 const 2 100.00 Using index

The difference here is that you're using a derived table, but it's still using the index. My expectation is that this would perform equally quickly as version 1, as long as the database is not resource constrained - if you're bumping up against memory or CPU limits, the second query may behave slightly more unpredictably.

However...

The theoretical approach is no substitute for having a test environment with test data, and tuning this thing in representative conditions. I doubt that the real query you're building will be as simple as the examples...

Comment: You are right, the real query will not be that simple and I agree your expectation about version 2

Answer (score 0):

For that simple pair of queries, the one involving the "derived table" (subquery), will definitely be no faster.

There are other cases where a derived table can be faster.  This includes case where a `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT` decreases the number of rows *before* doing the `JOIN`.